# Why is a table badly formatted when using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying to display data read from a file into a website. I want it to be formatted into a table. Here is the code to set up the table headers:

```
let table = document.getElementById("outputTable");
table.innerHTML = `<thead><tr>`;
for(const attribute in student_sample){
     table.innerHTML += `<th>${attribute}</th>`;
}
table.innerHTML += `</thead></tr>`
```

However, instead of creating a table row with headers, it creates MULTIPLE rows with one header in each row. It stacks the headers one after the other instead of lining them up in a single row. Any way of how to get over this error? The code works but it's just the formatting of it that is not good.

Comment: You cannot add only opening tags to the DOM - this is not the server-side, this is DOM.

Comment: Why has the edit for `</head></tr>` been approved.  Yes, it's incorrect but that should have been a comment..   Don't modify the code, it might have been the reason for the problem, and then nobody could help..

Comment: @Keith You are correct and I have reverted that change.

Comment: @Keith my bad. Before approving the edit I changed it on my code, but the outcome was the same, so that's why I ended up approving it. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add only opening tags to the DOM `table.innerHTML = '<thead><tr>';` - if the browser made that the innerHTML it would create an invalid DOM, even if your next lines of code address that.

Instead, create a `string`, and apply that to `table.innerHTML` when it's complete:

```
let table = document.getElementById("outputTable");
let tr = '<thead><tr>';
for(const attribute in student_sample){
     tr += `<th>${attribute}</th>`;
}
tr += '</tr></thead>'
table.innerHTML = tr
```

will work.

The other problem your code had is that you closed `thead` and `tr` in the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks you! I realized I need to polish my understanding of the DOM apparently.

Answer (score 0):

It's safer and more elegant to create elements directly and assign *text* rather than inserting text into a string that will be parsed as HTML later. I'd use `innerHTML` only when you're *given* an HTML string to insert, but I think you shouldn't try to create one when not necessary.

Try soemthing like this instead:

```
// theads are created automatically:
const thead = document.querySelector('#outputTable > thead');
Object.keys(student_sample).forEach(attribute => {
  thead.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'))
    .textContent = attribute;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need instead to `createElement` that creates `node` into the table which is the `thead` then you `appendChild` which is creates an element inside the `head` then for each attr in the loop creates an element and append it to the `tr`

So by that you don't need to add `innerHTML` text and it creates nodes and add them. It helps more if your code became more complex to debug.

```
let table = document.getElementById("outputTable");
let head  = document.createElement("thead");
let row =  head.appendChild("tr");
for(const attribute in student_sample){
let th = document.createElement("th");
    th.appendChild(${attribute});
    row.appendChild(th);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-??code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @AdamKipnis, Done